# How can I make a hidden select display with the right width when unhidden?

Tags: jquery, forms, dom, layout

In my form, the user selects between data representing a text or number value.  When they select number value, I want a units selection to appear next to it.  That functionality is all working fine, however, I get a different display depending on whether the unit selection span starts hidden or not.  If the unit selection starts visible (undesired), the unit selection field will possess a positive length.  However, if it starts off hidden (by enabling the commented out line below) the unit selection will appear as a scrunched-up selection of no width.  The content in the surrounding grid fields display appropriately regardless.

Note that at the time of developing this I haven't populated any options for the select field yet, though I allow the user to add their own entries.  I would want the field to remain the same size regardless of content to match up visually with other rows.

```
var unitSpan = $('<span>')
                    .attr('id', "unit_selection_" + transactionNum)
                    .attr('style', "grid-column-start:8; grid-column-end:10")
            //      .attr('hidden','hidden')
                    .appendTo(linkSet);
$('<span>')
    .text("units: ")
    .appendTo(unitSpan);

var unitSelect = $('<Select>')
    .attr('class', "chosen-select-single-select chosen-units")
    .attr('id', "newRelationshipRecipientUnits" + transactionNum)
    .attr('name', "newRelationship_" + transactionNum + "_unit")
    .attr('style', "width: 150px;grid-column-start:8;grid-column-end:10")
    .appendTo(unitSpan);
```

Comment: Since asking this I've had an idea of something to try, if not the skills to test it.  What if I created the elements without the hidden attribute, but then immediately called the code to hide the element?  I've been experimenting with 'on' and 'ready' events added to the unit_selection_x span to produce this behavior, but don't know if I'm using them correctly even if they are the right choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the visibility style instead of hidden, the unit span will still consume space in the layout so you won't need to play with the width.

```
var unitSpan = $('<span>')
                .attr('id', "unit_selection_" + transactionNum)
                .attr('style', "grid-column-start:8; grid-column-end:10")
                .css({'visibility':'hidden'})
                .appendTo(linkSet);
```

then use

```
unitSpan.css('visibility','')
```

to make the element visible.

Also if you use the jQuery css() method you won't clobber your style value.  It looks like you're repeating "grid-column-start:8; grid-column-end:10" because of this.

```
var unitSpan = $('<span>')
            .attr('id', "unit_selection_" + transactionNum)
            .css({"grid-column-start" :"8", "grid-column-end":"10", "visibility":"hidden"})
            .appendTo(linkSet);
```

then use either of these to display it instead of resetting the entire style which can cause other issues.

```
unitSpan.css('visibility','');

unitSpan.show();
```